# Citrix Workspace Uninstall

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, citrix

Windows 10 22H2

Citrix Workspace 1912

When attempting to uninstall Citrix Workspace as such...

`TrolleyExpress.exe /Uninstall /Silent /NoReboot`

About half-way through the uninstall process, the Add Account window appears (below), then disappears about a minute after that. Is there any way to suppress this Add Account window during the uninstall process? Can't understand why that would appear during an uninstall anyway.

[image: Citrix Workspace Add Account Window]

Comment: Kill the associated process before you uninstall the installed application.

Comment: Sadly, the associated process appears to be the TrolleyExpress.exe uninstaller. Can't terminate the uninstaller before we initiate the uninstaller.